Search and replace strings in text fields in all tables in MariaDB database, based on a table with original strings and their respective replacement
I have a large database, and in it there are several tables with different variants of text fields (VARCHAR, LONGTEXT, MEDIUMTEXT etc).
In these text fields there are sometimes a link to a video on Vimeo. Almost all of the videos they point to have been moved to YouTube. Almost being key here.
I have a lookup table for all the moved videos, with three columns: "id" (INT), "old_url" (VARCHAR) and "new_url"(VARCHAR).
What I want to do is pick the first "old_url", search through all the text fields in all the tables in the database for that particular url, and replace it with whatever is in "new_url" on the same row. Then I want to pick the next "old_url" and do the same and continue down the entire lookup table (there are 2667 rows so I don't want to do this manually, one by one).
My problem is that the urls that need to be found and replaced are deep inside texts, and some of them occur more than once, even in the same field, and every instance needs to be replaced.
I've tried creating a stored procedure to do this but failed miserably. Either it does nothing or I get an error message. Here's my latest attempt, I know it doesn't work, but I don't know why. (I'm definitely not an expert on SQL)
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE update_urls()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE column_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
        AND DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR', 'TEXT', 'MEDIUMTEXT', 'LONGTEXT');
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO table_name, column_name;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ', table_name, ' t ',
                          'JOIN url_mapping m ',
                          'SET t.', column_name, ' = REPLACE(t.', column_name, ', m.old_url, m.new_url) ',
                          'WHERE t.', column_name, ' LIKE CONCAT(''%'', m.old_url, ''%'')');
        
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;
END //

DELIMITER ;

I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this…

"large" is megabytes to some and terabytes to others.  How large?  I'd just dump the database and edit and reload the dump files

It's not large in Megabytes, but in the number of tables and columns (it's a Moodle database). Also, there are 2687 links in the lookup table, and at least two or three instances of each in the other tables. So it's definitely doable to dump and run it through some other script, but not trivial, I think.

"large" to some will mean dozens of tables and for others, tens of thousands of tables; always try to give approximate numbers.

You are of course absolutely correct. There are 478 tables in the database, plus my lookup table.

What we could suggest is to forget about the stored procedure and just write a script that will perform the task. The logic is quite simple and same as you have mentioned.

Connect to the database

Find tables with a field of required type
a. For every table do
i. For every row in the lookup table do

   1. retrieve old_url
   2. retrieve new_url
   3. retrieve the content of column that contains string
   4. use regular expressions to match old_url and replace with new_url
   5. update the table when url has changed



If you decide to use Python or whatever else programming language, you will find that it is way easier to handle strings via regular expressions than trying to come up with SQL to do that.

I'm seriously considering using sed on the dump instead of doing it in SQL. However, as I'm pretty sure it's possible to do it in SQL I'd really like to learn how to do that too…

Much simpler...
Do the replacement on the SELECT.  If, for example, the old is "mydomain.com/"  and the new is "YouTube.com/", then
SELECT ...,
       REPLACE(URL, "mydomain.com/", "YouTube.com/"),
       ...

The cost of doing a simple REPLACE during SELECT is trivial.
If the transliteration is more complex, this may not be practical.
Add a stored FUNCTION to do the replacement if it is not something simple, or if there is a chance of the base changing in the future.

And how do you propose the select statement should look?

I added an example.

Sorry, but that isn't helpful at all. As I mentioned from the start, there are more than 2600 urls to replace, and I need to look up each individually, and then do a global search and replace for each.
Anyway, I've decide not to use SQL for this and have written an script to do it with awk instead.
